# Aerodynamic kid's trailer with suspension

Tags: trailer

I'm looking for an aerodynamic kid's trailer to tow behind my Velomobiel Quest. Some corner points:

- Needs to be attached at axle height
- don't care for the coupling, because that needs to be replaced anyway
- suspension is a must
- large enough for one up to 8-10 year old kid with a bit of luggage, e.g. swimming pool stuff, something to eat/drink
- two-wheeled (trikes can't tow inline trailers)
- aerodynamics are pretty important
- rain-proof

I live in Germany, so it should be sold here or at least there should be a vendor that ships here.

**Edit:** A bonus would be if there was a way to somehow carry a kid's bicycle on the trailer such that the kid can ride as far as he wants and then climb into the trailer and I can continue.

Comment: wow, I feel your pain, but I don't have any suggestions. I don't recall even seeing a picture of one, ever. Good luck!

Comment: Wouldn't an 8-10 year old be able to ride quite well already? I have seen kids at maybe 13 doing crazy jumps that I can only dream of doing after years!

Comment: Definitely! Still, at the moment, the boy is five, and even at ten, I think there's an upper limit on how far he's ready to ride for himself. I live ~100km from the sea, which is a nice ride for me, but probably far too much for a kid.

Comment: Any kid trailer I have seen is a brick with wheels, but I would say that the extra weight adds in more.  Speed wise, I have taken a hit of no more than 6kph.  However, they don't really add much drag and your shell should displace a good amount air reducing its drag.  For suspension, the name brands have them, mine isn't one, but the kids never complain.

Comment: I was thinking that if the trailer has a handle for jogging, you *might* be able to strap the child bike to it.  I have not seen any kid trailers with a extended cargo area.  I could make my own, but that is because my kid trailer is steel and there is a cargo trailer that use the same frame.  I could weld them together or create a special connection off the back of the kid trailer to connect the cargo one too.

Comment: I think "aerodynamic kids trailer" is an oxymoron, especially when you add on the ability to haul another bike.  Best you're going to do is one of the units with a canvas cover.

Comment: How about a tandem bike? - the kid can help pedal when possible, and otherwise just hold on. Panniers could then be used for any luggage.

Comment: @MarkW: I'm asking specifically for a trailer for a velomobile (fully faired trike recumbent), so I fail to see how a tandem bike (you probably mean those half-bikes that attach to the rear rack) could be an answer here.

Comment: Ah. I see. I did not know what a velomobile was. Sounds fun. It was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @MarkW: Yeah, bad choice of words on my part.

Comment: Semi-related - consider communications.  How will you talk with your kids with multiple layers of bike between you ?   I'd suggest a pair of UHF walkie-talkies.  Cheaper ones should be adequate for a few metres, because yelling won't be clearly audible.

Comment: this http://www.scandinaviansidebike.com/specifications/ seems stylishly consistent with velomobiel, though would require quite a modification to act as a trailer.

Comment: @Gleb: Very sexy, although the vehicle would then be more than 1.5m wide...

Answer (score 4):

Generalisations on child-carrying trailers

- Based on stroller designs, so suspension is rare.
- Small wheels on cheaper designs.
- Seat is positioned for visibility and for an adult not to stoop too far to attend to the child. This is bad for stability and aerodynamics.
- Built like tents: frame with some kind of fabric over it. I've seen trailers/strollers with mesh fronts and ones with rollable plastic fronts, but as the overall shape remains a modified brick with fluttering fabric, I doubt they'll be very aerodynamic. Your velomobile is designed to have a minimised wake, so the trailer gains no aerodynamic advantage from following it.

What I would do: Make my own.

- Find a suspended cargo trailer or design and construct one from tubular sections of aluminium or steel.
- Create a fibreglass clamshell from scratch [using insulation board for the former, like the Kingsbury Quattro](http://www.kingcycle.co.uk/page8.htm)
- Or find a junk fibreglass boathull, invert it and add a vertical section until the interior height is sufficient. Fit a polycarb window on each side, but your child probably won't appreciate a porthole which shows the rear of your velomobile.
- Use good hinges and hydraulic struts to hold the shell open (like a car hatchback)
- If the shell needs catches or straps to hold it shut, there should be a release mechanism on the inside.

Comment: Actually, there are quite a few makers of kid trailers that have suspension nowadays. However, your points are still valid. While building my own trailer certainly crossed my mind and I think I've got the skills to pull it off, I fear that could take quite some time and money and wanted to check whether there are any commercial options.

Comment: Thanks for the link btw. That is more or less exactly the way I was thinking to do it.

Comment: A hard shell would add at least another 20 pounds weight, more than offsetting any advantage from the (hopefully) aerodynamic shape.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The Quest weighs ~30kg ready-to-ride (i.e. with spare tubes, spare tyres, pump, food, drink), and you can easily get away from most upright cyclists, even well-trained ones on less-than-6kg-bikes. It's the aerodynamics that matters most at high speeds.

Answer (score 2):

Both the Qeridoo [Sportrex 1](http://www.qeridoo.com/index.php/de/produkte/fahrradanhaenger/sportrex1-2014) and the Chariot 1 from [Thule](http://www.thule.com/en-us/us/products/active-with-kids/multifunctional-child-carriers/single-child-carriers/thule-chariot-cougar-1-avocado-_-10100534) have suspension, are rainproof, have an aerodynamic profile, have axle attachments, and have two wheels (with an optional third for running, etc)...

Qeridoo is even a German brand, so it shouldn't be hard to get in Germany...

But I don't know if you could fulfil the rest of the requirements (8-10 years old kid, possibility of carrying the bicycle at the same time, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the links, but both of these are still bricks with wheels. I was thinking along the lines of "drop with wheels", just like a velomobile